# What is the best way to handle sensitive data in PowerApps and Lists?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, data-security

I have only been using PowerApps for about a year now and I've received a request to create an application that compares tables based off of an existing Access database.  The big concern is that the existing database has sensitive data in its inputs (specifically, credit card numbers).  We do not currently have Dataverse, so I've been using SharePoint Lists for my tables, but my experience has been that we have to give full read/write access to each table to each app user, so simply not displaying the sensitive data is insufficient for security purposes.  How can I protect the data but still allow access to the tables in the application?

Comment: There are a LOT of requirements for storing and surfacing credit card data. I'd review [PCI compliance](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/what-is-pci-compliance/) before settling on Sharepoint + PowerApps as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scenario may help you have a reference:
User A can see an item in the list, but user B cannot see it in the list.

(1) The item has unique access to user A.

(2) The current view contains a filter, only showing file which is created by A.

(3) The file may in draft status and B is unable to see the draft.
In list settings -> versioning settings, when enable 'Require content approval for submitted items?', you could set specific user to see the draft items (items which is in pending status)